# How to assert argument list using Mockery

Tags: php, unit-testing, mockery

I want to assert the argument values with expected value of mine using mockery in php unit test case

```
 public function getTrack(TrackOption $trackOptions)
    {
        try {
            $buildCondition = array();
            $sql = 'SELECT * 
                 FROM xyz tbl'
            $where = " WHERE 1";

            if ($name) {
                $where =  " AND tbl.name =".$name;
            }
            $sql .= $where;
            $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();

            $query = $this->_rcEm->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
            $results = $query->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
            return $results;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I want to assert the `$sql` with expected value.
Any help.........

Answer (score 0):

in Mockery you do this by

```
$mock->shouldReceive('createNativeQuery')
->with('my-expected sql', \Mockery::type(ResultSetMapping::class));
```

If you havn`t found out already